# Reading from string C

Tags: c

Is there a function in c that that reads then next character for instead after "-"? For instance to check if the user entered in -o instead of -t or another character followed by-/

Comment: Just a vague guess, but do you maybe want [`getopt`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt)?

Answer (score 0):

Seems easy enough to write yourself:

```
const char * dash = strchr(the_string, '-');
if (dash) printf("The char after the dash is %c\n", dash[1]);
     else printf("There was no dash in the string.\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe? Just assign what you're checking to var.

```
char *var;
if(!strncmp(var, "-o", 2))
     //rest of code
```

To clarify some stuff with the strncmp() function in case you don't know it, though it's pretty straight foward, it takes two **const char*** to compare and a maximum number of characters to compare. Also it needs a **!(NOT)** since strncmp() returns 0 if true;